# Access Active Record Object Attributes in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with the following associations:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transportation_vehicle
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :parts

  def scrap(buyer, part)
  ...
  end
end
```

How would I access owner and parts in the scrap method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`owner` or `self.owner`.

Comment: thanks Jordan. Do I need the @?  I'd imagine owner would be an instance variable rather than a class variable.

Comment: to answer my own follow up, no need for @

Comment: "owner" is a method, in fact. Like many of Rails features, I believe it's generated on the fly using method_missing.

Comment: As an aside: in ruby, class variables have two @'s(`@@variable`), instance variables one (`@variable`) and things without can be either local variables or methods (which can be confusing at first, but once you get used to it it really is quite handy).